# What is this weird locale and how do you fix it?

Tags: iphone, ios, internationalization

One of my apps isn't working because the iPhone is reporting a null locale. Even when  setting the language and region to English/USA, this is the result on the Language & Region screen:

[image: unknown currency sign]

and the bug in my app still occurs. That's 0xa4 "currency sign" at the bottom, according to Wikipedia:

> The currency sign ¤ is a character used to denote an unspecified currency.

So it seems that even iOS does not understand the locale. How does this happen with a real phone and how do you fix it?

This is an iPhone 12 mini on iOS 14.7.1. Unfortunately it's not my phone so I have limited access to debug it. I have not been able to reproduce on my own devices.

Comment: My phone settings are identical to your screenshots (except I use Celsius). This looks like a bug to send to Apple. Have you tried changing the settings to see if the bug will go away, e.g. change the phone language to Korean, then back to English; change the region to Korea, then back; etc.?

Comment: Talked to the person who has this phone and screwing around with the locale eventually fixed it. It is still a mystery to me how they got into this state and why the first locale change didn't work.